# How to repair or at least analyse non booting debian?

Tags: grub2, hard-disk, cryptsetup

I have an Acer Swift 3 with a Kingston NVMe SSD that worked under Debian 1x until last week. At that time I ran Tails, rebooted and ... was not able to get into grub anymore. Acer: "No drive detected"

## Bios

The InsydeH20 Setup Utility (F2 very shorty after power on) shows

> HDD Model Name: KINGSTON RBUSNS8154P3...

> SATA Mode: Optane without RAID.

However, in its Boot menu I do not detect this drive. When e.g. trying a Super Grub 2 usb stick, I see

> Boot Mode: UEFI

> Secure Boot: Disabled

> Boot priority order: Linplus lite (the usb stick)

## Try Rescatux and Super Grub 2

Booting from USB I get into grub Minimal BASH.

```
grub> ls
(memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)
```

When doing

```
set prefix=(hd1,gpt1)/efi/debian
insmod normal
normal
```

I get into the grub menu I once saw so often. Having options

- Debian GNU/Linux
- Advanced option for Debian GNU/Linux
- System setup

### Starting the old system over minimal GRUB

Selecting *Debian GNU/Linux* the system starts again. However, I have an encrypted boot/home/... partition, that gives now errors:

> Volumen group not found

> Cannot process volume group

> cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=f20...

> mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

Then the cryptsetup part repeats itself until an (initramfs) prompt is shown in the Busybox built-in shell.

### Try hd0

Did not get the Super Grub 2 or Rescatux to boot. The last time I waited for 10 minutes after doing

```
ls (hd0,msdos1)/
```

gives *unknown filesystem*. The same for (hd0) only.

## Accessing the drive in external case

I was - at least once - able to decrypt the partition that does not react on booting using the PureOS disk utility (see Starting the old system over minimal grub).

Comment: Optane is often the issue. Have you tried with drive set to AHCI? Many systems also need UEFI & SSD firmware updates. Asus Zenbook UX425EA w/Intel Iris Xe Graphics - turn off optane with Windows Optane app
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373
removal (setuprst.exe and setupoptanememory.exe - both from Dell Acer Swift 5 (2019) ctrl-s  in UEFI required to be able to change to AHCI mode.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2427570

Comment: Tried that - No bootable device.